# Unable to select date in calender

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am using `multiDatesPicker` for calendar which works fine with default calendar options.

In my case I am appending an extra `span` tag to calendar dates so after appending the `span` tag, it is not selecting the dates on click.

here is how I am appending the span tag

```
$(function() {
  $('#custom-date-format').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: "y-m-d"
  });
  $('.ui-state-default').prepend($('<span>A</span> <span>B</span>'));
});
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/543w1pg3/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid using `prepend($('<span>A</span> <span>B</span>'))`. Another thing, why are you using `<span>` when you can pick multidates without using it.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#custom-date-format').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: "y-m-d"
  });
  $('.ui-state-default');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>

<div id="page">
  <div id="demos">
    <ul id="demos-list">     
      <li class="demo">
        <div id="custom-date-format" class="box"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have element `<a class="ui-state-default">NUMBER</a>` where datepicker script gets the value of this tag, i.e. NUMBER. When you add span elements into `a` tag, the content becomes invalid number, that's why date selection doesn't work on click. As solution you can play with css for example:

`.ui-state-default::before {
  content: 'A B ';
}`

Comment: There will b class changes for each letter so I need them in a html tag

Comment: I understand, but it's the way datepicker script works, it requires the innerHTML of `a` tag to be the valid number, you can't add span elements into this tag because it becomes broken then.